# Is there a way to restart an iPhone or iPad instead of just "power off"?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

That's because currently, you have to press Home button and see the turning wheel for the shut down, and then wait, and then start the iPhone or iPad again.  Is there an obvious or hidden secret method to just restart (or reboot) it?

P.S. the current Android 7.0 actually has this option, and is handy if I can just choose it and not look at it or walk away and 1 minute later it is all ready to use.

Answer (score 2):

Actually there is a way in *restarting* an iOS device. It's better known as 'soft reset'. Hold down Home button and lock button for a few seconds and your device will restart.

Comment: but this kind of restart is known as a forced restart... on the desktop computer, it is similar to CTRL-ALT-DEL or pulling the power cord... if any app or OS is saving data or adjusting data in a file, then those files can be corrupted. I am not sure about how Home + Lock(Power) Button does it (on iPhone 7, it is Home + Volume Down button by the way), but if it is the same as "cut off power now and just restart no matter what", then it is the same as pulling the power cord on a desktop computer

Comment: @太極者無極而生 the soft reset is not recommended to do every now and then. But as it's quite unlikely that you will have several applications opened up and working while you attempt to restart your device, it's an applicable way to restart the device without waiting for the shutdown to power it on again. As we are talking about a mobile OS it is _not_ similar to a comuputer and pressing CTRL-ALT-DEL or pulling the power cord. iOS is designed to work even after cutting power. So is every mobile OS -just in case of failuring battery for instance. PS: Thanks for the info about the iPhone 7's buttons :)

Comment: I have been a programmer for 30 years... that's not true: if power failure occurs, or it is some sort of forced restart, it is possible that data can be corrupted, no matter it is desktop or mobile device. It just depends on the app or the OS. Any app can very well compacting data or writing some info to its info file, and if it is forced restart or battery failure, the file or compacting can be corrupted, and not all app can handle corrupted data from this point on

Comment: @太極者無極而生 well that is almost what I was trying to say. It is not impossible that data gets corrupted when there is some sort of restart. It just should not commonly happen, precisely because it depends on the OS.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, as of iOS 10 there is no way to just restart iOS without shutting it down and powering it back up or jailbreaking the device.

Comment: This is kind of incorrect: you can do a soft reset as pallox mentions below which achieves the same thing the OP wants.